# why Auto-complete function not working after client side event fire?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Auto complete function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%=NALkTxt.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService.asmx/GetLookUp") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                scroll: true,
                scrollHeight: 180,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=CmbHdn.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});

</script>
```

The above function is working on page load but after any button click or event fire it is not working.

Comment: what error it throws ?

Comment: Are you doing partial postback?

Comment: does the console show any script errors? usually when a script is working but then stops it is because there is a javascript error

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21603746/1131841

Comment: @Son Great Please Mark my answer usefull

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603559/jquery-events-not-working-after-postback-in-asp-net